# How can I reinitiate a singleton?

Tags: c++, c++17

I know this might sound strange but I would like to reinitiate a singleton to set all its variables back to default.
I have the following singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
    public:
        static Singleton &getInstance(){
            static Singleton instance;
            return instance;
        }
        Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
        Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete;
        Singleton &operator=(const Singleton &) = delete;
        Singleton &operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;

        static void clearSingleton(){
            //Recreate instance object??
        }

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        //etc...
}
```

My program does a lot of changing of the variables like:

```
Singleton::getInstance().a = 5;
Singleton::getInstance().b = 8;
//etc...
```

After a while I need all variables to be reset. I could of coarse add a reset function to the singleton that would set all the variables but since they are so many, and it is easy to forget to add new variables to the reset function, I would just want to drop the singleton and recreate it. In that case all variables would be reset automatically.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can't do it with the class designed this way because the getSingleton method is the only place where the variable is in scope.  If you returned a shared_ptr<> instead it could be reset with a new instance.   Or you could just make it a namespace with accessor functions instead of a class.

Comment: Want to add that needing to reset a singleton kinda points to the fact that this shouldn't be a singleton.

Comment: Assuming you've done your research about why the singleton design pattern is often considered bad, what is the problem you decided to solve with a singleton? Why did you pick a singleton for the solution? And what is the problem you want to solve by "resetting" the singleton instance?

Comment: I am not promoting Singletons but this time I had to deal with it. Short answer is that the Singleton was used from different places in the code that I did not want to touch and I needed to reset all its variables. To take a shortcut, and not have to add a function that would reset every variable, I wanted to just recreate the singleton.

Comment: Turns out, you can't use `Optional`, without a public constructor of some sort. One option is to manage the memory yourself, but it's dangerous. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe6e8d7ea0e16a90

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just default the move-assignment operator, but make it private:

```
class Singleton {
        Singleton &operator=(Singleton &&) = default;
    public:
      // ...
};
```

you can write:

```
static void clearSingleton() {
    getInstance() = Singleton{};
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ovf3nf).

You can do this for all the special member functions, so you might as well, to be consistent.

Comment: This is simpler and probably better than my answer, but it's worth noting that making the assignment operator private has a few weird side effects, namely that they can be found during overload resolution and cause build failures. They're almost never a real problem, but they do exist.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's interesting, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you cigien, this worked perfect for me. Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. And thanks Mooing Duck for the warning.